# ASP.NET for Windows Mobile Screen Size

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-mobile

I'm developing a site that needs to display nicely on a Windows Mobile device. For some reason, a standard `<div>` on a page always scrolls out to view the entire page, despite the contents being in the top left corner. Is there a way to have the screen zoom to a particular portion of the page automatically?

Comment: have you tried to implement a responsive design? that's not only will fit precfectly for a windows mobile device, it will work nice for other devices as well, in fact not only for smartphones but to a wide range of devices such as tablets and different Pc resolutions look http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Bootstrap isn't really an option for my application. It's a very specific application that will only run on mobile devices of a particular screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to set the width and height atributes of the div element?
Something like:
`<div style="width:250px; height: 250px;">Content</div>`

P.S.: IMO a responsive design would be the best option.